# XmlPullParser stops reading

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Hey guys. I want to parse the XML file below, but after finding the first sub-element of "Mo" it stops working. Does anyone know why? Can anyone help me with this?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<StPl Klasse="3BHET" Version="Version 10- gültig ab 01.04.2013" Update="12.4.2013 7:57">
  <Mo Stunden="11">
    <1 Fach="IE1" Lehrer="FZ" Raum="307" />
    <2 Fach="ES1" Lehrer="GLM" Raum="307" />
    <3 Fach="ES1" Lehrer="GLM" Raum="307" />
    <4 Fach="NW2" Lehrer="SM" Raum="307" />
    <5 Fach="RISL" Lehrer="TUV" Raum="015" />
    <6 Fach="AT1" Lehrer="PE" Raum="307" />
    <7 Fach="AUT" Lehrer="TEA" Raum="307" />
    <8 Fach="AT1" Lehrer="PE" Raum="307" />
    <9 Fach="NW2" Lehrer="SM" Raum="218" />
    <10 Fach="FI" Lehrer="STT" Lehrer="SX" Raum="303" Raum="307" />
    <11 Fach="LTC1" Lehrer="KK" />
  </Mo>
</StPl>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your parser ?

Comment: Is there any exception in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp) :

XML Naming Rules
XML elements must follow these naming rules:

**- Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character**

Comment: Thanks, im just a poor beginner ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is invalid, you can not use a number as the first character of a element name. Take a look to the XML Validator (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp). You can find more information about the XML Syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).